# Issue using imported Bootstrap mixins in nested rules

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, mixins

I have a problem with using imported mixins from Bootstrap framework (3.3.5) in LESS.
The following code is a quick way to reproduce it.

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";

.a {
    .b {
        .c {
            .d {
                .navbar-form;
            }
        }
    }
}

// This directive should be redundant but actually changes the output CSS when present
.a .b .c .d {
    .navbar-form;
}
```

The result when compiled with lessc contains (among a lot of things) the following directive that comes from Bootstrap's `navbar-form` class:

```
.a .b .c .d {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

If I remove the second block - which IMHO is totally redundant - this directive is not included and thus the final rendering of the page is broken.

Did I miss something? Does it look like a bug? I could not find anything about that so far.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. See [for example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn.a%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.b%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.c%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.d%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.navbar-form%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%40import%20%5C%22https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Ftwbs%2Fbootstrap%2Fv3.3.5%2Fless%2Fbootstrap.less%5C%22%3B%5Cn%22%7D). Are you sure you did not oversimplify the test snippet?

Comment: You're right, your file on less2css does compile correctly, and it does too on my configuration. The difference I get when I keep the second block is only that directives are included twice, which is totally expected. I have to find another minimal test that reproduces the problem because I keep getting compilation issue with my project's files. Thanks

Comment: Found it, the problem happens when using `.navbar-default` on `.a`. Check it [there](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40import%20%5C%22https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Ftwbs%2Fbootstrap%2Fv3.3.5%2Fless%2Fbootstrap.less%5C%22%3B%5Cn%5Cn.a%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20.navbar-default%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.b%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.c%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.d%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.navbar-form%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%22%7D).

Comment: I see now. Well, you'll wonder but the result is expected because `.navbar-default` has *another* `.navbar-form` defintion, which  takes percedence over the global one since it's defined in more local scope (as soon as you expand in `.a`). Either way, the important thing to understand is that the whole approach you're trying to use is faulty and flawed: Bootstrap CSS rulesets are not designed and never meant to be used as mixins. For more details and for more proper approach see [these Qs](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/cefc873a78fa12924462) and comments there.

Comment: I get it, thanks for your help. Damn I was hoping this was the key to use Bootstrap in a more semantic way. I guess I'll have to find an alternative.